# Merging InputProcessor and GestureDetector

Tags: java, libgdx, input, gestures

I'm planning to make a simple soccerball app. When I attempt to drag the ball, I use the **touchDragged()** from **InputProcessor** to move the ball left or right. Next, while holding before releasing, I use the **fling()** from the **GestureDetector** to set the power. However, when I'm trying to set the input processor of both the implementing **InputProcessor** and the **GestureDetector**, it didn't work.  Moreover, whenever the last time you set the input processor and that would be either the two of them. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, you're calling:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(processorX);
```

twice?  It just sets a global variable, so that's why only one sticks.

To support multiple input processors simultaneously, you want an [`InputMultiplexer`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html).  You can add multiple `InputProcessor` instances to the multiplexer and it will pass events to them in the order the processors were registered.

However, I think you'll still run into problems because both of your input processors are trying to "eat" the same input events (touch events).  One of them will consume the events, leaving the other with nothing.  Unless you can separate where on the screen each input processor owns (e.g., if the power-setting is a separate area of the screen from the soccer ball).  Or, you could build your own multiplexer that knows which "mode" the game is in, and forwards events to the appropriate input processor.  Its hard to say without more concrete information about your system.

Comment: It's either to set a flag or in one of the methods under _InputProcessor_, it has to be set to _false_.